# Retrieve a column from a table then insert it to a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just created a table in SQL 2008. This table has two columns.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
[pkey] [bigint] not null,
[Number] [int]  not null
)
```

Now I want to insert values into it. The first column can be obtained from another table `dbo.OldTable`. It has many records and I don't want to manually insert the data. The second column `Number` can be a `0` in each row. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable](pkey, Number)
SELECT Column, 0
FROM dbo.OldTable
```

Comment: @Love Even if this answer was correct, the answer by EliGassert is the same and was posted earlier than mine, so you should accept his answer instead of mine

Comment: very kind of you to say so, thanks.  But no worries if he/she doesn't change it, just happy to help :)

Answer (score 6):

you can do a bulk processing of your table data.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(pkey, Number)
SELECT pkey, 0
FROM OtherTable
```